# Add two matrices in python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I'm trying to write a function that adds two matrices to pass the following doctests:

```
  >>> a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
  >>> b = [[2, 2], [2, 2]]
  >>> add_matrices(a, b)
  [[3, 4], [5, 6]]
  >>> c = [[8, 2], [3, 4], [5, 7]]
  >>> d = [[3, 2], [9, 2], [10, 12]]
  >>> add_matrices(c, d)
  [[11, 4], [12, 6], [15, 19]]
```

So I wrote a function:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

And then I wrote the following function:

```
def add_matrices(c, d):
    for i in range(len(c)):
        print map(add, c[i], d[i])
```

And I *sort* of get the right answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Matrix library

You can use the `numpy` module, which has support for this.

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> b = np.matrix([[2, 2], [2, 2]])

>>> a+b
matrix([[3, 4],
        [5, 6]])
```

---

### Home-grown solution: heavyweight

Assuming you wanted to implement it yourself, you'd set up the following machinery, which would let you define arbitrary pairwise operations:

```
from pprint import pformat as pf

class Matrix(object):
    def __init__(self, arrayOfRows=None, rows=None, cols=None):
        if arrayOfRows:
            self.data = arrayOfRows
        else:
            self.data = [[0 for c in range(cols)] for r in range(rows)]
        self.rows = len(self.data)
        self.cols = len(self.data[0])

    @property
    def shape(self):          # myMatrix.shape -> (4,3)
        return (self.rows, self.cols)
    def __getitem__(self, i): # lets you do myMatrix[row][col
        return self.data[i]
    def __str__(self):        # pretty string formatting
        return pf(self.data)

    @classmethod
    def map(cls, func, *matrices):
        assert len(set(m.shape for m in matrices))==1, 'Not all matrices same shape'

        rows,cols = matrices[0].shape
        new = Matrix(rows=rows, cols=cols)
        for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(cols):
                new[r][c] = func(*[m[r][c] for m in matrices], r=r, c=c)
        return new
```

Now adding pairwise methods is as easy as pie:

```
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Matrix.map(lambda a,b,**kw:a+b, self, other)
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Matrix.map(lambda a,b,**kw:a-b, self, other)
```

Example:

```
>>> a = Matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> b = Matrix([[2, 2], [2, 2]])
>>> b = Matrix([[0, 0], [0, 0]])

>>> print(a+b)
[[3, 4], [5, 6]]                                                                                                                                                                                                      

>>> print(a-b)
[[-1, 0], [1, 2]]
```

You can even add pairwise exponentiation, negation, binary operations, etc. I do not demonstrate it here, because it's probably best to leave * and ** for matrix multiplication and matrix exponentiation.

---

### Home-grown solution: lightweight

If you just want a really simple way to map an operation over only two nested-list matrices, you can do this:

```
def listmatrixMap(f, *matrices):
    return \
        [
            [
                f(*values) 
                for c,values in enumerate(zip(*rows))
            ] 
            for r,rows in enumerate(zip(*matrices))
        ]
```

Demo:

```
>>> listmatrixMap(operator.add, a, b, c))
[[3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

With an additional if-else and keyword argument, you can use indices in your lambda. Below is an example of how to write a matrix row-order `enumerate` function. The if-else and keyword were omitted above for clarity.

```
>>> listmatrixMap(lambda val,r,c:((r,c),val), a, indices=True)
[[((0, 0), 1), ((0, 1), 2)], [((1, 0), 3), ((1, 1), 4)]]
```

**edit**

So we could write the above `add_matrices` function like so:

```
def add_matrices(a,b):
    return listmatrixMap(add, a, b)
```

Demo:

```
>>> add_matrices(c, d)
[[11, 4], [12, 6], [15, 19]]
```

Comment: I really appreciate the work but it's a little above my paygrade. I just started teaching myself how to program last week from the book "How to think like a computer scientist".  But seeing as how this website kept coming up in google searches while I was working through the book, I'm sure it will help someone more knowledgeable than me. Thanks.

Comment: @gergalerg: No problem, I'm happy to explain why your answer is almost correct. This is extremely important: There is a difference between returning a value, and printing a value. **In general, you do *not* want to call `print` (or any other "side-effect code") in a function; you will want functions to return *new* values that you can *later* print.** e.g. Your function is not returning anything: `add_matrices(c,d)==None`. You want `add_matrices(c,d)==[[..],[..],[..]]`. Though all these answer seem different, they *all* create a **new** blank matrix, fill it in, and return it. =)

Comment: @gergalerg: [need more space] This is called functional programming, and is extremely important. Anyway to further illustrate the misunderstanding with doctests, typing both `1` and `print(1)` in the interpreter will show the same result. However `1==1` is True, while `print(1)==1` is False (the value of `print(...)` is nothing). The moral here is that we must return a value from functions, or else we will be unable to reuse them later in other functions. You will not need to call `print` when dealing with doctests, and in general only need to call it once (or never) in a large program.

Answer (score 7):

```
def addM(a, b):
    res = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        row = []
        for j in range(len(a[0])):
            row.append(a[i][j]+b[i][j])
        res.append(row)
    return res
```

Answer (score 4):

One more solution:

```
map(lambda i: map(lambda x,y: x + y, matr_a[i], matr_b[i]), xrange(len(matr_a)))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import izip

def add_matrices(c, d):
    return [[a+b for a, b in izip(row1, row2)] for row1, row2 in izip(c, d)]
```

But as said above, there is no need to reinvent the wheel, just use `numpy`, which is likely to be faster and more flexible.