# How can I use a for iterator as a function parameter in Python?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, matrix, iterator

I'm trying to call a function that creates matrices from user input, but it says that i haven't defined something.

```
lstA = []
lstB = []
lstC = []

def get_list(data):
    lst = []
    for i in range(4):
        aux = []
        for j in range(4):
            aux.append(data)
        lst.append(aux)
    return lst

lstA = get_list(int(input(f'A i[{i}] j[{j}]: ')))
lstB = get_list(int(input(f'B i[{i}] j[{j}]: ')))
lstC = get_list(lstA[i][j] + lstB[i][j])
```

The program should take two 4x4 matrixes from user, by putting each informed number inside the `lstA[i][j]` and `lstB[i][j]`.

Finally, `lstC` is used to sum `A` and `B`.

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
NameError: name 'i' is not defined

[Program finished]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You are trying to use a variable defined in a function you haven't called yet? That doesn't make sense. Please explain your end goal

Comment: I want the program to take 2 matrixes and sum them into a 3rd one.

Comment: So are `lstA`, `lstB` supposed to be matrices? And `lstC` is the sum?

Comment: The function should create these 3 arrays, and I need to use the for iterator to append values into them.

Comment: Ok it looks like the function is already appending values to them, what is missing?

Comment: Nothing, but I get a error message when trying to use the 
for iterators as parameters

Comment: When you say "iterators", what exactly are you referring to? All I see you are doing is passing `int(input(f'A i[{i}] j[{j}]: '))` to the function for `lstA`. That's not an iterator, so what iterator are you referring to? And where is it being used as a parameter?

Comment: The ```i``` and ```j```.

Comment: Ok I think I might be catching on now. Are you wanting to have the user input values for each matrix? So as the function runs, it will ask for the value at `A[i][j]` and populate that part with what the user enters and it will do this for all 4x4 matrices?

Comment: smac89 Yes, exactly

Comment: Alright that's good. Can you please update your question to reflect this goal?

Comment: smac89 edited ^^

Comment: Thank you, and I've just posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

To read the data into the matrices, make a function like this:

```
def get_lst():
  mat = [[]] * 4
  for i in range(4):
    mat[i] = [0] * 4
    for j in range(4):
      mat[i][j] = int(input(f'mat[{i}][{j}]: '))
  return mat
```

This function will ask the user for input for each element of the matrix and populate that position with what the user entered.

Now this is how you use it:

```
lstA = get_lst()
lstB = get_list()
```

As for summing the elements of the matrices, refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6382798/2089675)